# Importing Orders from a CSV file

Tags: orders, ce-1.7.0.2, import

How have others imported orders from a CSV file into Magento? Are there any good scripts?

Comment: Try not to ask such a broad question, but make it much specific. Eg. How can I import orders via the SOAP API? Etc. Everyone here will have imported orders in many different ways suitable for their needs, but your phrasing in your question won't lend to any one correct answer. FYI - the down vote wasn't me. I believe (when edited) this can be a valuable question.

Comment: @sonassi, I kept it general because I'm not sure of the best way to do this. Usually when I ask questions like this, I get people giving advice as to how they've imported orders. I guess I didn't think that there would be that many ways to import an order, either using the API or SQL, right?

Comment: Well, there's a myriad of different ways. SOAP API, REST API, PHP API, SQL, then variations on data flow etc. But certain methods will be more appropriate to you than others. Be more specific as to your needs. Eg. It needs to integrate with a legacy ERP system etc.

Comment: @sonassi, so is the web service API what you normally use then, or do you import orders directly into the database with SQL?

Comment: We don't ***ever*** manipulate the DB directly. Whatever import method we use will be dictated by the circumstances and requirements of the client.

Comment: okay, I guess but I would have expect there to be a standard way for most people. Magento offers a way to import products and customers but not orders so I guess I incorrectly assumed there was a more standard way to import an order. I tried to edit the question to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inchoo examples are always a good starting point
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Maybe start from there and ask some more specific questions, cause creating an order is a pretty broad subject :)

Comment: Thanks Sander, I will take a look at that. Have you tried it, does it work well?

Comment: I've written a few order imports, the most important thing; test for each and every possible case. Orders are very sensitive to fawlty data.

Comment: Makes sense, I just hate to reinvent the wheel. Considering that there are so many Magento scripts around, I figured people would have one they'd recommend.

Comment: True, but as every import is different is important to understand all the models and data for yourself, even when using an example. Good luck with the import